# How to find critical path / max clock rate for multicycle datapath?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I was wondering how to obtain the longest time it takes for an instruction to complete in a multicycle datapath. I understand Load word is the longest instruction, but I have heard that the process for calculating the time it takes for an instruction differs in multicycle datapaths. I have heard that the max time depends not on the critical path, but on the critical stage. Can someone please help/clarify this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The critical path is the longest computation that could happens in any 1 cycle, and that will determine the max clock rate (cycles per second) and also cycle time/duration — assuming all cycles simply share the same clock & clock rate, which is a reasonable assumption.

(Varying cycle speeds and asynchronous/unclocked logic are pretty advanced subjects and presumably not applicable here.)

On a multicycle processor, single instructions are split into multiple cycles running different pieces of hardware, so each of those cycles (datapaths) should be examined to determine which is on the critical path.  The set of cycles that needs to be examined is all possible cycles for all possible instructions, not just for loads.

For example, even though the load instructions is likely the slowest overall instruction because of a high cycle count (e.g. 5), some other instruction type, say multiply (e.g. with cycle count of 4), might have a longer critical path on one of its cycles that could limit the max clock rate for the whole processor.

The max time to completion for all instructions is calculated by first adding up the number of cycles for each different type of instruction, taking the max among them, and then multiplying by the duration of a single cycle determined as per the above.

---

If we want to improve the clock rate, we identify the cycles near the critical path cycle and potentially split the top one or top several each into two cycles.  The max clock rate then will rise (cycle time will lower) to the limit of some other cycle that wasn't split.

An analysis, on a given workload, could tell if this results in a net improvement or not, since any change in performance is a trade off between whatever cycle time improvement is obtained versus that some certain instruction(s) have now one more cycle (albeit a faster cycle) than before.  Different workloads/programs will most certainly yield different specific answers in such analysis as to improvement.